# How to auto update /etc/hosts file entries inside running Pod without entering the pod

Tags: kubernetes

How can we auto-update (*delete, create, change*) entries in `/etc/hosts` file of running Pod without actually entering the pod?

We working on containerisation of *SAP* application server and so far succeeded in achieving this using *Kubernetes*.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
```

Since we are using host network approach, all entries of our VMs `/etc/hosts` file are getting copied whenever a new pod is created.

However, once pod has been created and in running state, any changes to VMs `/etc/hosts` file are not getting transferred to already running pod.

We would like to achieve this for our project requirement.

Comment: Hi Jayesh and welcome to StackOverflow! You will see that a couple of us have been editing your question to make it fit into the style of the site a bit better. It would be useful to hear a bit more about your project requirement, so that subject experts can provide relevant advice without needing to guess what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes does have several different ways of affecting name resolution, your request is most similar to [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/) and related pages.

Here is an extract, emphasis mine.

> Adding entries to a Pod’s /etc/hosts file provides Pod-level override of hostname resolution when DNS and other options are not applicable. In 1.7, users can add these custom entries with the HostAliases field in PodSpec.
>
> **Modification not using HostAliases is not suggested because the file is managed by Kubelet and can be overwritten on during Pod creation/restart.**

An example Pod specification using `HostAliases` is as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hostaliases-pod
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  hostAliases:
  - ip: "127.0.0.1"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.local"
    - "bar.local"
  - ip: "10.1.2.3"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.remote"
    - "bar.remote"
  containers:
  - name: cat-hosts
    image: busybox
    command:
    - cat
    args:
    - "/etc/hosts"
```

One issue here is that you will need to update and restart the Pods with a new set of `HostAliases` if your network IPs change. That might cause downtime in your system.

Are you sure you need this mechanism and not [a service that points to an external endpoint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors)?